# PySNMP: Dynamic fields

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to walk a table with PySNMP and only pull back specific fields.  Currently I have the following code which works well.

```
def walkTable(community, hostname, port, tableName, fields):
    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData(community, mpModel=0),
                              UdpTransportTarget((hostname, port)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(tableName, 'ifAlias')),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(tableName, 'ifHCInOctets')),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(tableName, 'ifHCOutOctets')),
                              lexicographicMode=False):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'))
            break
        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                fooBar(varBind)
```

The above function takes a variable called fields.  This is a string array of fields I'd like to pull from the table but I cannot figure out how to do this dynamically.

Currently what I've tried is

```
def walkTable(community, hostname, port, tableName, fields):
    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData(community, mpModel=0),
                              UdpTransportTarget((hostname, port)),
                              ContextData(),
                              for x in fields:
                                   ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(tableName, x))
                              lexicographicMode=False):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'))
            break
        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                fooBar(varBind)
```

Which doesn't work.  Is there any way to dynamically create ObjectType for nextCmd()?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
...
nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData(community, mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget((hostname, port)),
        ContextData(),
        *[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(tableName, field)) for field in fields])
...
```

Nitpick: if you want higher performance, keep persistent `SnmpEngine` instance around and reuse it for all your SNMP calls.